# How to add className to component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components

I have a navbar component that I created for react.
When I call this component on different pages, I need to change the classNames.

For example : I want my "" component to have a different class on one page and a different class on another page.

```
const ServicesCiso = () => {
return (
    <div className="hero">
        <NavBar/>
        <div className...
```

How can i add className in this code ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `className` as props to this component and pass the preferred className on the page you are rendering it

```js
const ServicesCiso = ({ className }) => {
return (
    <div className={className}>
        <NavBar/>
        <div className...
```

```
<ServicesCiso className="my-class-name" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the className from out side to your component via props however you also need a default class in init case

I have suggestion this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames ( combine classes )

example

```html
View
   - ServicesCiso.js
   - ServicesCiso.css
```

```js
import ./ServicesCiso.css;
import cn from('classnames');

const ServicesCiso = (props) => {
   const {className} = props;

   return (
     <div className={cn('hello', className}}>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: That's not what i mean. I want to add className to my component where I call it.

Comment: So you can pass className from outside and use it in your component base on your situation